# Possible to integrate analytically positive part of a function?

Tags: integration

I'm currently stuck with the following situation. It might be a stupid question but anyway. Let's say I have to integrate the positive part of a function.

In other words, is there any analytical way to integrate something like :
$\int_a^b \max(f(x),0) ~\mathrm{d} x$

Or more exactly (I don't think it changes anything but just in case) :

$\iiint g(y)*\max(f(x,z),0) ~\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y\mathrm{d}z$

Where $f(x,z)=\sum_{n=0}^4\sum_{m=0}^2x^nz^{2m}$

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Do you mean in closed form? It will depend on what $f$ is.

Comment: Closed form means with boundaris ? I will add f(x,z) in the description then !

Comment: No, closed form means written out explicitly in terms of "known" functions (what exactly "known" means depends somewhat on context).

Comment: The idea is to be able to have an expression for such an integration to avoid numerical methods to gain CPU-time !

Comment: Well...no, you can't do that without saying something about what $f$ is. In particular, you would need to analytically write down the set where $f$ is positive in order to even start doing that.

Comment: Isn't the desciption of $f$ I added enough to do so ?

Comment: Oh, now I see the edit, I missed it before. Well, since $f=\sum_{n=0}^4 \left (z^4+z^2+1 \right ) x^n$, the problem of finding where $f$ is positive boils down to solving the equation $x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1=0$. It turns out that the roots in this case are all complex so in fact your $f$ is a positive function. Thus $\max(f,0)=f$.